# adding 1 to last row of mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm trying to select the last ID in my table then add 1 to the value. I am selecting the last row just find the problem is that I'm having problems with the +1 I think this is because it's an array but I'm not sure.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$pin = $row[0]+1;

echo ($row[0]); //returns the id
echo ($pin);    // returns null
```

Any thoughts on this would be great.

Comment: Does this help? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`SELECT max(id) + 1 from users`

But if you are doing an insert, just grab `mysql_last_insert_id()` to find out what was just inserted. Otherwise you will have issues with concurrency.

Your id is setup as `AUTOINCREMENT` correct? You should never never never never ever assign the primary key yourself. this is the db servers job.

Comment: concurrency isn't required just as long as the ID and $pin are unique. And yes the DB is `AUTOINCREMENT` is `mysql_last_insert_id()` valid for mysql4?

Comment: Concurrency is an issue because another process (another user on the website) could do an insert before you assign the pin, so when you insert, the pin and id do not match.

Comment: Thanks Byron, but won't `mysql_last_insert_id()` run AFTER the `INSERT`? I'm just trying to get a placeholder number BEFORE the insert. Maybe I'll go the `UPDATE` route

Comment: You can't get the id before you insert, only after. Seems like the pin setup should be on a page after they enter some basic info. You can even have your app forward the user to pin setup after they save their user info. You could always just do `rand(0,9999)` if you just want a default pseudo random pin.

Comment: Just to nitpick, the correct function is `mysql_insert_id`, there is no "last"; the MySQL function is `LAST_INSERT_ID`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `mysql_insert_id()`.

```
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

That will display the most recently inserted id.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions.  The easiest given the code you already have above may be:

```
$pin = intval($row[0])+1;
```

That said, there are definite improvements/optimizations to be made in the code that other answers here touch on.  But if you're looking for the shortest path from what you have to what you want, that one change might be it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not reliably determine the next inserted id before the actual insert takes place. The last record may have been deleted, but that does not change the auto_increment value of the table. Also, if two (or more) concurrent requests happen, both can check the last inserted id and find the same value. When inserting the rows, both will get different ids...

Comment: in my case pin dosen't have to be unique so this should be okay